# Xcode project workspace missing files after cloning from github

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm somewhat new to Swift and to development tools in general. After researching a lot about a question I had, I finally decided to ask it here. I hope it makes sense and be useful to others like me.

I wanted to take a look at a project in github: https://github.com/jyoo980/crypto-exchange

I clicked "Clone or download" and then "Open in Xcode". After that is done, I quit Xcode and I navigate to the project folder in the terminal and do a "pod install", which runs without any errors or anything. I go back to Xcode and I see files missing from the workspace marked with red. And of course the build fails because of "Build input files cannot be found". [Missing files in workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcIkN.jpg) [Build input files missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fOfk.jpg)

What I noticed is, in Finder, the files are actually in the project but they are in subfolders, instead of the Model group as follows: [Finder project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biA4Z.jpg)

So my question is, why would the project be structured like this in Xcode? And why would it not work right away when I clone it from github? Could this be a CocoaPods problem? Of course I can go to the "red" files and specify their location in Xcode and when I point them the problem is gone, but I would like to understand what's going on here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this happening in all your projects ?

Comment: Well, for all other Swift projects I imported and the ones I created myself don't have this problem. But none of them have CocoaPods or they aren't under version control either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue, you are correct. A cloned project should work right away. You should report the issue to the repo owner on github, or fix it yourself and create a pull request.